# Using MonadError with transformers possibly based on IO

Tags: haskell

How can `MonadError` be used for error handling in transformer stacks that may or may not be based on `IO`?

I want to use `throwError` and `catchError` from `MonadError` (in mtl) to handle failures inside a monad transformer stack. The base of the stack might be `IO` or something else like `Either e` (where e is some error type). I feel like this should be possible without adding an ExceptT layer.

However, I can't figure out how to implement this in a way that works both for `IO` and for other possible bases. The `MonadError` instance for `IO` is defined as `MonadError IOException IO`, which restricts the error type to `IOException`. Of course, this doesn't make sense if there is no `IO` monad in the stack. Using a different error type breaks things with `IO`.

For example, consider this function (using FlexibleContexts here):

```
f :: MonadError String m => Int -> ReaderT r m ()
f 0 = throwError "This is an error."
f n = return ()
```

`runReaderT (f 1) 0 :: Either String ()` evaluates to `Right ()` as expected, but `runReaderT (f 1) 0 :: IO ()` gives an error:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘GHC.IO.Exception.IOException’ with ‘[Char]’
        arising from a functional dependency between:
          constraint ‘MonadError String IO’ arising from a use of ‘f’
          instance ‘MonadError GHC.IO.Exception.IOException IO’
            at <no location info>
    • In the first argument of ‘runReaderT’, namely ‘(f 1)’
      In the expression: runReaderT (f 1) 0 :: IO ()
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = runReaderT (f 1) 0 :: IO ()
```

I tried writing an alternative `MonadError` instance for `IO` that uses `String` errors, but it seems MonadError has a functional dependency which makes this impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to make a class which `String` and `IOException` are both instances of, and use that when throwing.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import GHC.IO.Exception
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Except

class StringException a where stringException :: String -> a
instance StringException IOException where stringException = userError
instance StringException String where stringException = id

f :: (StringException e, MonadError e m) => Int -> ReaderT r m ()
f 0 = throwError (stringException "yikes")
f n = pure ()

main = do
    print (runReaderT (f @String @(Either _) 1) 0)
    runReaderT (f 1) 0
```

Comment: That makes sense. I see that `IOException`is an instance of `Exception`, so maybe `f :: (Exception e, MonadError e m) => Int -> ReaderT r m ()` is what I'm looking for, though I haven't found a way to convert an `IOException` to an `Exception e => e` (I feel like I'm missing something obvious here).

Comment: @Quyk The type `(Exception e, MonadError e m) => ...` says that the caller of `f` gets to choose any `Exception` instance they like, and `f` will work with that. So that probably isn't going to fly, since you have only a few very specific instances that work.